# Есть ли в c# уже готовый массив всех возможных вариантов байта?

Tags: c#, массивы, библиотека, байты

Мне нужен готовый массив из 256 элементов типа byte, в котором будут написаны все вариации байта. Просто мне не хочется писать такой массив самому, и потому хочу узнать нет ли уже готового варианта?

Comment: Заполнить такой массив - дело одной строчкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 256).Select(x=>(byte)x).ToArray()
```